# Why does data.table change order of the columns?

Tags: r, data.table

I encountered the following puzzling (for me) behavior of the `data.table` when combining `get` in J with `.SDcols`: columns order is not preserved, as in:

```
mtcarsDT <- setDT(copy(mtcars))
vars <- c( "disp", "hp", "mpg")
fun <- "median"
mtcarsDT[, lapply(.SD, median), .SDcols = vars]
#     disp  hp  mpg
# 1: 196.3 123 19.2
mtcarsDT[, lapply(.SD, get(fun)), .SDcols = vars] 
#     mpg  disp  hp
# 1: 19.2 196.3 123
```

Note that this doesn't happen without `.SDcols`:

```
mtcarsDT[, lapply(.SD, median)]
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp  drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1: 19.2   6 196.3 123 3.695 3.325 17.71  0  0    4    2
mtcarsDT[, lapply(.SD, get(fun))] 
#     mpg cyl  disp  hp  drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1: 19.2   6 196.3 123 3.695 3.325 17.71  0  0    4    2
```

I am wondering if anyone can shed light on that behavior: is it a bug or a feature? In the latter case how can I deduce the order that columns will appear?

Ultimately I want to name the new columns according to original variable names with a call like:

```
newVars <- paste0(vars, "_median")
mtcarsDT[, (newVars) := lapply(.SD, get(fun)), .SDcols = vars]
```

which now produces incorrect results.

Comment: Can you just use `mtcarsDT[, lapply(.SD, fun), .SDcols = vars] `?

Comment: From "eyeballing," it looks like without `get`, the order given in `.SDcols` is the order in which the columns are returned. With `get`, the order of the columns in the original data.table is preserved.

Comment: It's filed as a bug here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2036